# How to use LWC with a Node.js application

Tags: lightning-web-components, node.js

I want to use LWC (Salesforce Lightning Web Component) for my node application but I could not find neither a documentation nor a way to do it. 
 How can we use LWC in a node application (for instance Express.js)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got the answer, actually it was easy because the Salesforce team already provided the solution.

Under the link https://lwc.dev/guide/install, when you install lwc with npx, it asks "Use custom Express server configuration" and you can say it yes and the Express.js server configuration is already under index.js.